# ZIndex and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, z-index

I have an image which constitutes the subject of a question and I want to place buttons on top of it for the user to click.

I have an object which positions a sprite (a rectangle with a background image which is transformed)

And I have an ItemsControl which positions the buttons using Margin.left and top. Like so

```
<Grid x:Name="imageGrid">
        <local:spriteView Canvas.ZIndex="10" x:Name="QuestionImage" Sprite="{Binding QuestionImageSprite}" />
        <local:ImageAnswers Canvas.ZIndex="50" x:Name="AnswersImages" Answers="{Binding answers}"></local:ImageAnswers>
</Grid>
```

I want `AnswersImages` to be positioned directly on top of `QuestionImage` but `QuestionImage` is pushing `AnswerImages` down and `AnswerImages` is also affecting the position of `QuestionImage`.

How do I stop them from doing that? Can I force them to be positioned absolutely within the `ImageGrid`

Comment: The XAML you provided should work. Can you provide a simplified example, without your custom controls, that we can cut and paste to reproduce the issue you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Canvas.ZIndex` declarations. If your putting them both in a grid without specifying additional Column and Row definitions they will lay ontop of each other in the order they appear in the `XAML`

Comment: so instead i need to put them both in row 1 col 1?

Comment: I tried but they are still flowing around each other. maybe it's because i'm positioning the buttons with Margin.Left and Margin.Top.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion should definately work. Get rid of any margins or Canvas positioning properties and it should be fine

Comment: Is there a way to debug the final xaml with all the controls embedded into each other. I think there's an issue with padding.

Comment: I had to change the `ItemsPanel` of the control which was outputting the buttons to use a `canvas` and the VerticalAlignment needed to be set to top also. Thanks for the tips, Silverlight Spy helped a lot.