# Change z order of image controls at runtime windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, z-order

I have several image controls placed on a canvas. I want to change the `z order` of a selected image control when user click on the app bar button.

In the `image control` class I have

```
    public int ImageZOrder 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _imageZOrder;            
        }
        set 
        {
            _imageZOrder = value;
            Canvas.SetZIndex(ImageControl, _imageZOrder);
        }

    }
```

And in the app bar

```
    private void appBarFront_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentCharObject.ImageZOrder += 1;
    }
```

I was expecting to see the selected image is brought to the front of other image controls immediately. However the above code does not work. Obviously I am missing something. Do I have to redraw the image controls on the canvas with the new z order value?

**Update 1**

In the XAML I have the following. Each image was added as children to `cvsNote`

```
    <Grid x:Name="GridCanvas" Grid.Row="0">
        <Canvas x:Name="cvsNote" />
    </Grid>
```

**Update 2**
I just want to add that the 'image control' contains in a particular class where it is just one of the class many properties.

Comment: Do you actually have your images on a `Canvas`? Or are they on a `Grid`? The reason I ask is because the answer on this question suggests that if you have them in a `Grid` to make sure they are in the same row/col: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076024/zindex-and-silverlight

Comment: I have the `Canvas` placed inside the main `Grid`. See updated code.

Comment: what if instead of `Canvas.SetZIndex` you had `this.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, _imageZOrder)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the ZIndex in code.

Assuming this xaml:

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Tap="gridTapped">
    <Image x:Name="ImgA" Source="Assets/A.png" />
    <Image x:Name="ImgB" Source="Assets/B.png" />
    <Image x:Name="ImgC" Source="Assets/C.png" />
</Canvas>
```

You could change which image is on top with the following:

```
private int TopZindex = 10;

private void gridTapped(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    switch (rand.Next(0, 3))
    {
        case 0:
            Canvas.SetZIndex(this.ImgA, ++TopZindex);
            break;
        case 1:
            Canvas.SetZIndex(this.ImgB, ++TopZindex);
            break;
        case 2:
            Canvas.SetZIndex(this.ImgC, ++TopZindex);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. With little modification, I placed the code on the page instead of inside the class and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of the child images in your canvas

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Name="a"/> 
    <Image Name="b"/> 
    <Image Name="c"/> 
</Canvas>
```

change the order

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Name="c"/> 
    <Image Name="a"/> 
    <Image Name="b"/> 
</Canvas>
```

will change the z order.

If you want to get this done in code, for instance:

```
List<Image> AllImages= new List<Image>();
...
Canvas.Children.Remove(img1); //This will remove img1, 
Canvas.Children.Add(img1);    //This will add img1 to the tail.
```

Comment: So he'd have to remove all of the images, re-order them, then re-add them all to the `Canvas` to update the Z-index of one image?

Comment: No, you can just swap the order, no need to recreate the images.

Comment: I want the user to be able to change any image `z order` to their liking while the app is running.

Comment: you can do so when a user clicks a specific image, put this image to the tail, which will be rendered on topmost.

Comment: Ah - well if it's simple to re-order them on the fly, this could be a solution, although I'm not sure why the OP's way of setting the z-index doens't work.

Comment: So I have to remove all existing images and re-add them to the `Canvas` according to their z-order value?

Comment: @PutraKg, as commented above, no need to remove and re-add, just reorder the sequence, I think it is very clear and simple to change the element index/order in a collection, note that the Image is class not a struct, and therefore it is a reference object, and reordering is a piece of cake ...

Comment: I know your suggestion will work but I am trying to this via code and I can't rewrite the XAMl at runtime.

Comment: @PutraKg, see the updated answer. If you understand what XAML does, translating it to code is not a headache

Comment: Ah.. that's what I thought, so I have to remove/and re-add the particular image. Let me try that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I've tried it and it seems to work. However, it would be nice if I could play with the `z-index` itself to reorder the image controls (as they are added dynamically according to user input and can change on the fly). Then next time when I need to restore the image controls on the canvas, I can refer to their z-index value and reorder them accordingly.